# Routing missing URL link as parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor

I need my web application to pull up a band detail page based on the band name in the URL, without creating a cshtml file for every band. For example, 
myurl.com/someband
I need to route to the someband page, using someband as the parameter, but not as a querystring parameter with a question mark and = sign.

One idea I had would be to change the IIS 404 error to route to the index page and maybe send the url and then strip out the band name as a parameter. That doesn't sound very clean.

The expect results should work like facebook.com/yourid

Comment: What do you mean by `withou creating a cshtml file for every band.`? Which cshtml fill return for different band.

Comment: @TaoZhou, In a core project there is a cshtml file for each link. For exdample, here's the sample privacy page link/cshtml.

//@page
//@model PrivacyModel
//@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>

I don'rt want to generate a new cshtml page for each band, but rather one reusable page to display the band data I pull from SQL, but I want the link to be the domain + band name.

Comment: check the update answer.

Answer (score 0):

For resolving the parameter from route, you could try `Route` like

1. Controller with route

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       [Route("{band}")]
       public IActionResult Band(string band)
       {
           ViewData["Band"] = band;
           return View();
       }        
   }
   ```
2. View (Home/Band.cshtml)

   ```
   @{ 
       Layout = "";
   }
   <h1>@ViewData["Band"]</h1>
   ```

**Update**

It seems you are using Razor Page, try steps below:

1. `PageModel`

   ```
   public class IndexModel : PageModel
   {
       public string Band { get; set; }
       public void OnGet(string band)
       {
           Band = band;
       }
   }
   ```
2. View

   ```
   @page "{band?}"
   @model IndexModel
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
   }

   @Model.Band
   ```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. In the first example, ViewData["Band"] throws an exception because it's passing a null view. The second example works, but is it loading the band page into the index page? Sorry, I'm new to Razor pages and I'm trying to wrap my head around this. Also, is there a way to integrate a partial load so the page doesn't refresh every time a link clicked? My end goal is to persist a music player at the top as the user navigates the website.

Comment: @MotleyDrew What do you mean by ` is it loading the band page into the index page?`? What is the relationship between routing and persisting a music player?

Comment: A music player (basic HTML5 audio) that is streaming a song in the header/menu of the page will stop playing when a link is clicked. A partial load will allow the player to keep streaming as links are clicked.